# jQuery not loading (jquery-rails 2.2.1 & rails 3.2.1)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I started a rails application (my first) a little while ago following the official walk-through blog and modified it.  It seems my jQuery is not loading properly.
My application.js looks as follows...

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function() { alert('hello world'); });
```

Chromium gives me "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"
My application.html.erb starts as follows...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tanuki</title>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

I'm using a few gems including Devise 2.2.3 (not sure if it matters)
Any ideas?
Full repo is at https://github.com/MidnightDemon/tanuki

FIXED:  Apparently my ArchLinux was having issues with compatibility - Fixed by changing to Rails 3.2.13 and railties 3.2.13 (worked on OSX which was weird)